# Subview not visible/won't change background color - UIKit / Swift

Tags: swift, uiview, uikit

I'm learning Swift, and want to make a basic flashcard app. However, I've run into a problem: I want to have a "cardView" subview that has a black border around it to mimic the appearance of a flashcard. It will not show up. However, it does COVER the UILabel I have, which is only visible if I change the alpha value of the subview. When I print the background color, it returns 1 0 0 1, which I believe to be red. All I see is a white screen with the UIButton, and, depending on the alpha value of cardView, the UILabel. Here is my code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var cardData = CardData()
    var recall = RecallManager()
    var card1 = SimpleCard(id: 1, deckID: 1)
    
    var frontFacing = true
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //cardText.text = cardData.fetchCardProperty(id: 1, property: "front") as? String
    }
    
    override func loadView() {
        view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        loadSimpleCard(card: card1)
    }
    
    func loadSimpleCard(card: SimpleCard) {
        var cardText = UILabel()
        var fbButton = UIButton(type: .system)
        var cardView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200))
        
        cardText.text = "Test"
        cardText.textAlignment = .center
        cardText.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        
        fbButton.setTitle("Show back", for: .normal)
        fbButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.turnOverCard), for: .touchUpInside)
        fbButton.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
        fbButton.backgroundColor = .red
        fbButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(fbButton)
        view.bringSubviewToFront(fbButton)
        
        
        cardView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        cardView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        cardView.tintColor = .red
        cardView.layer.borderWidth = 20
        cardView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        cardView.alpha = 0.5
        cardView.isHidden = false
        view.addSubview(cardView)
        view.sendSubviewToBack(cardView)
        cardView.addSubview(cardText)
        cardView.sendSubviewToBack(cardText)
        print(cardView.backgroundColor)
        

        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            cardText.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor, constant: 0), cardText.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor, constant: 0),
            fbButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor, constant: 0), fbButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor, constant: 150), 

cardView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor, constant: 0), cardView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor, constant: 0)
        ])
    }
```

I've changed the constraints, tried different colors, set isHidden to false, both sent the subview to the back and to the front, changed the size and starting coordinates, but nothing will work.

Comment: You need to add width and height constraints for `cardView`. And be sure you set the `cardText` constraints relative to `cardView`, not `view`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set Height/Width constraint of CardView given frame is not solution. here it it

```
    cardView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100),
    cardView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100),
```

**//Full Code**

class ViewController: UIViewController {

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    //cardText.text = cardData.fetchCardProperty(id: 1, property: "front") as? String
}

override func loadView() {
    view = UIView()
    view.backgroundColor = .white
    loadSimpleCard()
}

func loadSimpleCard() {
    var cardText = UILabel()
    var fbButton = UIButton(type: .system)
    var cardView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200))
    
    cardText.text = "Test"
    cardText.textAlignment = .center
    cardText.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    
    
    fbButton.setTitle("Show back", for: .normal)
    fbButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.turnOverCard), for: .touchUpInside)
    fbButton.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
    fbButton.backgroundColor = .red
    fbButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.addSubview(fbButton)
    view.bringSubviewToFront(fbButton)
    
    
    cardView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    cardView.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
    cardView.tintColor = .systemPink
    cardView.layer.borderWidth = 20
    cardView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    cardView.alpha = 0.5
    cardView.isHidden = false
    view.addSubview(cardView)
    view.sendSubviewToBack(cardView)
    cardView.addSubview(cardText)
    cardView.sendSubviewToBack(cardText)
    print(cardView.backgroundColor)
    
    
    
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        cardText.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor, constant: 0), cardText.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor, constant: 0),
        fbButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor, constant: 0), fbButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor, constant: 150),
        
        cardView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor, constant: 0), cardView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor, constant: 0),
        cardView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100),
        cardView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100),
    ])
}
```

}